# How should I use ninject in a multiproject mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

My app is set up this way
Web
Data
Services
POCO Entities

Controllers use services (so they should be injected)
Services use Repositories (which I assume should also be injected)

I have this already set up so that the Controllers receive the service they need through Ninject but I not sure how to get this done with the services =>repositories

any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Bob has several blogs about repository pattern with Ninject and NHibernate. It's pretty much the same for all other OR Mappers:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/09/the-repository-pattern-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ninject.web.mvc](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) extension. It contains a sample application which illustrates how you could register the container in `Global.asax`.

Answer (score -1):

Simply set up your services' dependencies as well as the controller's dependencies.  Ninject will walk the dependency chain and resolve all of them.

for example,
`ProductController` has dependency on `IProductService`
`IProductService` is implemented with `ProductService` that has a dependency on `IProductRepository`
`IProductRepository` is implemented with `NHibernateProductRepository` that has a dependency on `ISession`.

when your `NinjectControllerFactory` attempts to resolve `ProductController`, it sees the dependency on `IProductService`.  it resolves that dependency as `ProductService`, and sees that it has a dependency on `IProductRepository`.  and it will continue on down the chain until it can resolve completely an argument.

so the important part is to Bind ANY dependencies, not just those in a Controller.

Comment: I understand that.. I have further explained my problem in another question... the problem is that my web app doesnt reference the Data project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939100/help-with-ninject-in-mvc3