# Help with Ninject in mvc3!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository, repository-pattern, ninject

Heres my problem.
My app has several projects.

- WEB (Controllers and views)
- Services
- Data (edmx and Repositories)
- Entities (POCO)
- Tests

So in my Web project I have the ninject configuration

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PublicPanama.AppStart_NinjectMVC3), "Start")]

    namespace Web{
        public static class AppStart_NinjectMVC3 {
            public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
                //kernel.Bind<IThingRepository>().To<SqlThingRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IContributorService>().To<ContributorService>();
            }

            public static void Start() {
                // Create Ninject DI Kernel 
                IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

                // Register services with our Ninject DI Container
                RegisterServices(kernel);

                // Tell ASP.NET MVC 3 to use our Ninject DI Container 
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I also want to add

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
```

But my Web project does not have a reference to the Data project.. and just adding the reference for this doesnt seem right..

what am I missing?
please help!

Comment: Why doesn't adding a reference to the Data project seem right? Presumably you have a reference to the Services project. Isn't it a similar issue?

Comment: you tried what the nuget mvc 3 package spits out and / or the ninject.web.mvc stuff?

Comment: @dommer: thats the point, my Web project uses the Services in the service project.. it has no reason to reference the Data project at all... other than defining what needs to be injected... my point is.. now that I have added ninject. I also need to add a bunch of references to the web project that doesnt need them at all... it's weird that no one finds this odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/

And dont forget to read @Brad Wilson's blog series (ref'd in article)

Comment: I dont see where the problem Im having is mentioned here. :s

Comment: @NachoF: You're not wrong - it's not in my answer directly. The problem is that a canned answer to your specific problem isnt going to give you the overview of how DI and ninject are best used with your app. The fact that you've got a small makeshift ninject integration reveals this for me. Regarding your specific question, the most relevant answer I've seen is Jeffrey Palermo's Onion archictecture notion which is covered in a blog and in ASN.NET MVC 2 In Action. There's no point in me trying to give the two paragraph subset that will fix that here.

Comment: Having said that, I'll try... Normally, if you look at the stuff I've cited and ninject.mvc, you'll see a `Kernel.Load("*.Services.dll")` or similar - this will give you some looseness (I havent read your question in detail or puzzled through it to know whether it's definitely the specific answer you need in this instance)

Comment: Yes, I figured it out.. it looks for all Modules and adds them. so i have succesfully dereferenced the Servicec project, added the Module there and voila.. thank you.

Comment: Wonderful. Highly recommend finding the onion architecture article and the associated chaper in ASP NET MVC 2 in action though as brain food.